# What do I print line this numeric pattern?

Tags: java, for-loop

I've been trying to figure out this for loop forever. It's probably simple but I feel like I've tried a million things. Can someone help me understand what the hell I'm missing? I've tried things like making a variable called total for 18.

The closest result I got is with: `System.out.print((i-6) + (i*i) + " ");`
But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Also, this answer is wrong too
but I guess I just don't understand something major.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    // your code here
}
// Output should be: -4 14 32 50 68 86
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Looks like `i *18 -4`

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

Correct would be to use step 18 in the loop, unless you need to have a loop from 0 to 6 with step 1:

```java
for (int i = -4; i <= 86; i += 18) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an arithmetic sequence starting from -4 with a common difference of 18.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
   System.out.print(-4 + 18 * i + " ");
}
```